# WebView is not loading for specific URL in Xcode 9 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, webview, ios-simulator

I am trying to load a URL using webView in swift 4. I tried https://www.google.co.in and it works fine. and the mobile site for the specific URL works fine with android. 
But when I tried this in the simulator, it is loading forever.

my code is below:

```
import UIKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.delegate = self
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.myurl.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.loadRequest(request)
        }


    }


   public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        activityIndicator.center =  CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.red
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
    {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

I don't think that my code is wrong. but I was wondering if I can do anything to make it work on simulator.

Thanks

Comment: Your issue is unclear. What actually happens with the code you posted?

Comment: When I run the app in simulator, webViewDidStartLoad is called. and it is showing activity indicator. but the webpage is not loading. I waited for more than 30 minutes and all I could see in the simulator was a blank page with activity indicator.

Comment: What happens if you enter the exact same URL into Safari in the simulator?

Comment: It is working fine in Safari in the simulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made a small project with your code and no problem in the simulator, https://www.google.co.in loaded just fine.

I noticed you mention you are using Swift 4, I think you should consider using WebKit View (`WKWebView`) since `UIWebView` is deprecated. In [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) you can see how to implement it, it's pretty straight forward.

If your certificate is not trusted you must add to Info.plist `App Transport Security Settings`, `Allow Arbitrary Loads` to YES. (This is not recommended).

The code is really simple, give it a try:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.myurl.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried WebKit View and the same happened. google ULR is working. but mine isn't. however the reason I did not use WebKit view was because, my deployment target is 9.0. thank you :)

Comment: On `https://www.myurl.com` the certificate is not trusted, you have to add in Info.plist `App Transport Security Settings`, `Allow Arbitrary Loads`.  Then you must implement this: `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) `.  I just edited the code to reflect this.  Also WKWebView is present since iOS 8 I think.